# "There is no application set to open the URL..." Message after updating to macOS Big Sur 11.4

Tags: macos, mac, applications, big-sur

I just updated my macbook air to Big Sur 11.4 and I get this message when I try to open Roblox.(see picture) When I try to "Choose Application" the Roblox selection is grayed out, and I can't click it. I had this same exact problem when Big Sur first came out, and I forgot how I fixed it. I remember that I did try to delete and re-download Roblox and it didn't help. It was something about changing the permissions I'm pretty sure but I have no clue how to get to that menu.
[image: message]
[image: "choose application"]
No past discussions on here have been a help and neither has google.

Thank you to anyone that can help!